# Java EE TDD starting point

Tags: java, web-services, rest, unit-testing, tdd

I want to apply TDD to my Java EE application.

The requirement is to create a company with a name and contact details. The entry point into the system is Rest and web service, depends on the client.

I'm struggling to find a starting point to write my unit tests.

Do I start with a stateless `CompanyService` bean (Rest and web service will use this service/bean) which takes in the parameters in a `create` method or do I start at Rest service and web service level and work my way down, i.e. the entry points?

Answer (score 2):

There's books written to answer this so it can't be covered properly in a short answer, but here's a starting point:

You start with an acceptance test for a simple bit of user functionality, e.g. create company with name only via web service.  Then you use TDD to create the code needed to satisfy the acceptance test.  You can do this either 'outside-in' or 'inside-out'.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Can you give me the name of the book that you are talking about.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to write a integration test in Arquillian as the starting point. Then as you try to make the integration test work you write unit tests to test the objects that is needed in isolation?

Comment: Yes, try http://www.amazon.com/Growing-Object-Oriented-Software-Guided-Tests/dp/0321503627 for a start